# Retrieving Int Value from SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, integer

I am trying to retrieve an integer from my SQLite database and my current query crashes my program.  This is what I have so far:

```
 */
public int getWin(String id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT " + COL3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + id + "'";

    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    db.execSQL(query);
    int win = Integer.parseInt(query);
    return win;
}
```

I am not sure why this will not work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the value SELECT ......... into a number as per `int win = Integer.parseInt(query);`.

For a SELECT statment you need you need to retrieve a Cursor (result set), via either the **query** or **rawQuery** SQLiteDatabase method and then extract the value(s) from the method and to then access the respective column from the respective row(s).

I believe that you would use something like :-

```
public int getWin(String id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rv = -1; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED default value to return if no row found

    String query = "SELECT " + COL3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + id + "'";

    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery(query,null); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED to get the Cursor returned
    // ADDED the following IF construct
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL3));
    }
    //int win = Integer.parseInt(query); //<<<<<<<<<< DELETED (commented out)
    csr.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED should always close a Cursor when done with it
    return rv; //<<<<<<<<<< return the value (-1 if no row found)
}
```

- This assumes that you just want the value from a single row as identified by the WHERE clause.

If possible it is recommended to a) not build the query with direct values (makes it vulnerable to SQL Injection) and to b) utilise the convenience **query** method.

Apply both **a** and **b** and your code could be :-

```
public int getWin(String id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rv = -1;
    String whereclause = COL2 + "=?"; //<<<<<<<<<< where clause without where and ? for value that will be passed
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}; //<<<<<<<<<< arguments used by the whereclause ? replaced on a 1 for 1 basis
    String[] columns = new String[]{COL3}; //<<<<<<<<<< the columns to extract as a String array
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL3));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```